# How to change themes in android smoothly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In my application i am using a splash screen for the application start up with the theme `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`.

After 2 seconds the app goes on to the main activity which uses this theme: `@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`.

One is in full screen, the other one is not. The transition between both is not smooth and it takes a while (~1 seconds) for the main activity to adjust to the status bar. Is there some trick to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no api level solution for this.  I suggest Using [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) for example changing background color and/or [PropertyAimation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) for changing view's properties like background color or text color. Then you can call `setTheme()` function of activity to apply your new theme. be careful that `setTheme()` must be called in `onCreate()` function before `setContentView`.